# Displaying heterogenous data in GTK+ tree view

Tags: python, gtk

I'm writing a music player frontend using Python bindings for GTK+.  The playlist is a TreeStore, with albums represented by the top-level items, and tracks by their children.

I want to separate the scanning of the music directory and reading the tags of the music files, based on the hunch that scanning the tags is more time-consuming than just adding the item to the tree store.  Hence, I intend to run a separate thread that goes over the playlist and fills in the tags.  For that end, the model items will consist of the following columns:

```
[ 'file_path', 'tags_filled', 'album', 'title', (more items for tags) ]
```

When the music directory is initially traversed, only `file_path` will be filled, and `tags_filled` set to `False`.  The tag-filler thread will set `tags_filled` to `True` and the rest of the columns to their values from the music file.

When it comes to displaying the described model, I want to display the rows differently based on the `tags_filled` attribute: When it's `False`, I want only the file path displayed, spanning the full widget width; and when it's `True`, I want only the tag values displayed in the separate columns.

Something like this:

```
| Artist | Album  | Date | Title                      | Duration |
|--------+--------+------+----------------------------+----------|
| AC/DC  | T.N.T. | 1975 | It's A Long Way To The Top | 5:15     |  <-- scanned
| music/AC-DC/1975 - T.N.T/02 - Rock'N'Roll Singer.MP3           |  <-- not yet scanned
```

Can you suggest how I can go over implementing this?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to merge cells of a tree view (yet). You'd have to use a table (deprecated since Gtk 3.4) or a grid for this. [Here's how to use these widgets](http://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/layout.html) for GTK 3 or check the PyGTK 2.0 Reference Manual, if you are using PyGTK.